# Django website is displaying "It works! Python 3.6.8"

Tags: django

I recently deployed a Django website on namecheap and it has been running properly not until yesterday when I started seeing:

```
It works!

Python 3.6.8
```

Please what can I do rectify this issue.

Comment: there is little information to go on here. Got logs? Spoken to the support team?

Comment: Sounds like your code somehow got overwritten by some out of box sample code. Any answer you get here is going to be speculative at best.

Comment: Likely something with the settings.py or urls.py. This is the initial message you get when you set up an app. So something must be unlinked somewhere to not show your pages

Comment: It looks like somehow it removed the existing code at the server, and for example replaced it with default server code?

Comment: The  ROOT_URLCONF in settings.py still points to the url module. It is 'projectname.urls'